# Storing Google Maps Markers in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am trying to store markers in an array then make it so I can later push the places api data to a list. I'm having trouble figuring this out.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd very much appreciate it.

```
      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
            allResults = [results[i]];
          }
        }
      }


  self.allResults = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.listPlaces = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      allResults.push([results[i]]);
    }
  };
```

`allResults` is a global array defined as `var allResults = [];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got the marker creation and list creation split up, but it would work more easily if you had them together, I think.  In your `for` loop, you aren't adding new items to your list, you're overwriting your list each loop.  You haven't included your whole code, but I also wonder whether your `listPlaces` function has access to your `results` list.  You're creating your markers in a way I'm not so familiar with, too.

Anyhow, here's how I would suggest restructuring.  You should define your observable array first, then add the markers to it.

```
// Other code up here
self.allResults = ko.observableArray([]);
// and other code.
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(results[i]);
    self.allResults.push(marker);
}
```

This would also be a fine time to add those markers to the map, right after creating them, but before putting them into the list.  But you weren't asking about that, so you may already have handled that elsewhere in your code.